# Simplifying the sum with binomial coefficients: $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n {2k\choose k}{2n-2k\choose n-k}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Identity involving binomial coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37971/identity-involving-binomial-coefficients)

> Simplify the sum: $$\sum_{k=0}^n {2k\choose k}{2n-2k\choose n-k}$$

So we can denote $a_n=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n {2k\choose k}{2n-2k\choose n-k}$ and see that $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n a_n x^n$ is a convolution of $b_n$ and $b_n$, where $b_n={2n\choose n}$, hence all we need to finish this is generating function for Catalan numbers. One derivative and we are done, $a_n=4^n$.

But this sum looks very nice and it's bugging me if has it any interesting combinatorial interpretation. Any ideas?

Comment: My recollection is that a combinatorial proof is known but hard.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/q/80649/152