# Proof of the identity $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom {2k}{k}\binom {2(n-k)}{n-k}=4^n$

Tags: combinatorics

> Prove the following identity :
>   $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom {2k}{k}\binom {2(n-k)}{n-k}=4^n$$

I am sorry, this topic is very new to me and so is this website.  I have looked at all the "duplicates" of this question on this website, but none have had an answer that I can comprehend.  I thought I was able to just plug each one into the binomial theorem and arrive at the answer, but my professor stated that I am using the theorem incorrectly.  I do not have an intuitive understanding of proofs yet.  Any direction will help!  Thank you.

Comment: Have you met generating functions?

Comment: We have not met generating functions yet!

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown - So far, we have been exposed to the binomial theorem, multinomial theorem, induction, and Pascal's Triangle.

Comment: In your title, you ask for a "combinatorial proof" which usually means bringing your problem to be in correspondence with a "real life" situation where you count certain "situations" in two ways (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_proof). Is it that ?

Comment: Well, there is not yet a solution using solely the combinatory properties. And I believe it is either calculation of combinations or an induction problem

Comment: A cousin issue : (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/80649).

Answer (score -3):

I am helping you on this one. I am trying to make reference to this equality:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n {{n}\choose{k}} = \sum_{k=0}^n {{n}\choose{k}} 1^k \cdot1^{n-k} = (1+1)^{k+n-k}=2^n$$
So, by the similar fashion (I will explain why it is the multiplicative)
$$ \sum_{k=0}^n {{2k}\choose{k}} \cdot{{2(n-k)}\choose{n-k}} = \sum_{k=0}^n {{2k}\choose{k}}1^k1^k \cdot {{2(n-k)}\choose{n-k}} 1^{n-k}1^{n-k} = (1+1)^{k+k} \cdot (1+1)^{(n-k)+(n-k)} = 2^{2k+2n-2k}=2^{2n}=4^n$$
This actually leads to the good end. But I will establish why or improve the solution.

It seems like the following is problematic.....
$$\sum_{k=0}^n {{2k}\choose{k}} \cdot{{2(n-k)}\choose{n-k}} = \sum_{k=0}^n  \frac{(2k)!}{k!k!} \cdot \frac{[2(n-k)]!}{(n-k)!(n-k)!} = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(2n)!}{{{2n}\choose{2k}}} \cdot \Big( \frac{{{n}\choose{k}}}{n!} \Big)^2$$

Comment: I thought I would have been able to plug in 2k, k, and 2n-2k into the binomial theorem, but I was far from correct.  I need a better understanding of what is going on. Thanks!

Comment: I am struggling too but I think the answer may be solve to the end.

Comment: Can check the first formula~~

Comment: Where you wrote “in similar fashion” and what followed,  this is what I did, and it is very wrong to do so.

Comment: I agree it is problematic because something is not easy to describe. Tt this stage, I am still performing calculations and hopefully reaching the right solution. 

I also read this and hopefully this notation may help a bit. http://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/27642007.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3A8047129bf57da060c7e9fc60607501ea

Comment: -1 that is no proof

Comment: Two users (and the OP) seem to think that $$\sum_ka_k\sum_kb_k=\sum_ka_kb_k$$ is legit?