# The horizontal pivot line of $\sin^2 x$ here is exactly $\frac{3}{8}$. Why?

Tags: calculus, integration, physics

I noticed that the horizontal pivot line (or $y$-coordinate of the centroid) under the curve $y=\sin^2 x$ between $0$ and $\pi$ is exactly $\frac{3}{8}$.  There may be no reason for me to find this strange, but it's just so neat.  Does anyone know why this is?

$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{\int_0^{\pi} (\sin^4 x) dx}{\int_0^{\pi} (\sin^2x) dx} = \frac{3}{8}.$$

Comment: Pardon me, but What is the definition of "horizontal pivot line"?

Comment: The OP is presumably referring to the $y$-coordinate of the centroid.  "Why" is a question worth thinking about. The usual argument for the location of the centroid tells us **that** the $y$-coordinate is given by the integral. There may be a more intuitive argument.

Comment: When finding the centre of mass of a given area under a curve, you would do so by finding the horizontal and vertical 'pivot lines'.

Comment: @AndréNicolas exactly. :)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Good instincts: it *is* interesting that the $y$-coordinate of the centroid is such a ‘nice’ numbers.

Comment: @Brian, Korgan: Can you explain what it is that you find so neat about the number $\frac38$? Is it just that it is rational and doesn't involve $\pi$?

Comment: @Rahul: It is at first blush a little surprising to get such a simple rational out of a context in which $\pi$ plays a prominent rôle. It’s perhaps rather less surprising after one has some experience, but I think that a beginning student should be commended for wondering whether there’s a simple, intuitive explanation.

Answer (score 4):

I had a mistaken argument before. It occurs to me to wonder how you know the value $3/8.$ The simplest way to find the two integrals is by using the identities
$$  \sin^2 x = -\frac{1}{2} \cos {2 x} \; + \; \frac{1}{2}   $$ and
$$  \sin^4 x =  \frac{1}{8} \cos {4 x} \; - \; \frac{1}{2} \cos {2 x} \; + \; \frac{3}{8}$$

Comment: Very nice use of the symmetry!

Comment: Is it obvious that the area below $\sin^2 x$ with that rectangle removed has its center of mass at $y = \frac12$?

Comment: @RahulNarain, it breaks up into four identical pieces, first with $0 \leq x \leq \pi / 4,$ then rotated 180 degrees to $\pi / 4 \leq x \leq \pi / 2,$ then reflected to $\pi / 2 \leq x \leq 3 \pi / 4,$ then rotated again to $3 \pi / 4 \leq x \leq \pi.$ We do not need to find the center of mass of any of the four pieces, they are identical, and the rotation takes care of forcing the $y$-coordinate of their collective center of mass being $1/2.$

Comment: If you take the piece below $y = \sin^2 x$ over $0 \le x \le \frac\pi4$ and rotate it 180° about $(\frac\pi4,\frac12)$, don't you get the piece *above* $y = \sin^2 x$ instead? Whereas what you want is the one above $y=\frac12$ and below $y = \sin^2 x$.

Comment: @RahulNarain, I will draw some pictures and see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose a general explanation for this phenomenon might be that the average value of $\sin^n\,x$ or $\cos^n\,x$ over $[0,2\pi]$ is pretty simple; it's just $\frac1{2^n}\binom{n}{n/2}$ if $n$ is even, and $0$ if $n$ is odd. This is clear if you write $\cos^n\,x = \left(\frac12(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})\right)^n$ and apply the binomial theorem; after integration over a period, only the constant term will remain.

A corollary is that if you take any polynomial over $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ whose coefficients are rational numbers, its average value over $[0, 2\pi]$ will be a rational number.

Comment: I find it striking that the average value of $\sin^n x$ or $\cos^n x$ over $[0, 2\pi]$ is the same as the value of $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{-1/2}{k}\binom{-1/2}{n-k} (-1)^k$.  (See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/80101/2370).)  I wonder if there is a direct connection?

Comment: @Mike: That's very interesting! But I can't get a good mental handle on your expression. Is there a combinatorial or other natural interpretation of it or of its summands?

Comment: I asked for a combinatorial proof of an equivalent sum [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/80649/2370).  In the question I proposed using lattice paths, but the answer I ended up finding uses colored permutations.  I would love to see a connection between either of these and the average value of $\sin^n x$ or $\cos^n x$.  I don't immediately see such a connection in either case, though.

Answer (score 2):

To determine the value of this quotient you don't even need to compute the integrals:
$$\int_0^\pi\sin^4 x\ dx= - \sin^3 x\ \cos x\Bigr|_0^\pi + \int_0^\pi 3\sin^2 x\ \cos^2 x\ dx = 3\int_0^\pi \sin^2 x\ dx- 3\int_0^\pi \sin^4 x\ dx\ . $$