# Value of $\sum_{r= 0}^{2019}\sum_{k=0}^{r}(-1)^k.(k+1).(k+2).\binom{2021}{r-k} $

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

What is tried was : $\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\mbox{Note that inside summation is }\quad\left.
\sum_{k = 0}^{r}\pars{-1}^{k}\pars{k + 1}\pars{k + 2}{2021 \choose r - k}
\right\vert_{\ 2021\ >\ 3} =
\left.\partiald[2]{}{x}\sum_{k = 0}^{r}{2021 \choose r - k}x^{k + 2}
\right\vert_{\ x\ =\ -1}
\end{align}  , now how to simplfiy the summation part which needs to be double differentiated or there is some other method to solve for that summation value too ?

Comment: I don't think your Latex rendered properly, please refer the MathJax reference.

Comment: Done @person...

Comment: There isn’t even a good closed form for $$\sum_{k=0}^r\binom{n}{r-k}=\sum_{k=0}^r\binom nk$$ so there probably isn’t a closed form for $$\sum_{k=0}^r\binom n{r-k}x^{k+2}$$

Comment: Yes i also think same but i meant the summation of inside part has a closed form of 2*n-3Cr , i am not sure of the closed form for the summation which needed to be diff twice

Comment: Anything good happen if you reverse the order of summation?

Comment: Why not if its leading to something gud by adding them both ? @GerryMyerson  and btw though what will be expression looks like after swapping the order?

Comment: $\sum_{r=0}^{2019}\sum_{k=0}^r$ becomes $\sum_{k=0}^{2019}\sum_{r=k}^{2019}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In seeking to evaluate

$$\sum_{r=0}^n \sum_{k=0}^r
(-1)^k (k+1) (k+2) {n+2\choose r-k}$$

we write

$$2 \sum_{r=0}^n [z^r] (1+z)^{n+2}
\sum_{k=0}^r {k+2\choose 2} (-1)^k z^k.$$

The coefficient extractor enforces the range of the inner sum:

$$2 \sum_{r=0}^n [z^r] (1+z)^{n+2}
\sum_{k\ge 0} {k+2\choose 2} (-1)^k z^k
\\ = 2 \sum_{r=0}^n [z^r] (1+z)^{n+2}
\frac{1}{(1+z)^3}
= 2 \sum_{r=0}^n [z^r] (1+z)^{n-1}
\\ = 2 \sum_{r=0}^n {n-1\choose r}
= 2 \times 2^{n-1} = 2^n$$

where we have used $n\ge 1,$ for $n=0$ we find $2[z^0] (1+z)^{-1} = 2.$

**Addendum.** We may also change the order of summation as asked in the
comments to get

$$2 \sum_{k=0}^n {k+2\choose 2} (-1)^k
\sum_{r=k}^n {n+2\choose r-k}
= 2 \sum_{k=0}^n {k+2\choose 2} (-1)^k
\sum_{r=0}^{n-k} {n+2\choose r}
\\ = 2 \sum_{k=0}^n {k+2\choose 2} (-1)^k
[z^{n-k}] \frac{1}{1-z} (1+z)^{n+2}
\\ = 2 [z^n] \frac{1}{1-z} (1+z)^{n+2}
\sum_{k=0}^n {k+2\choose 2} (-1)^k z^k.$$

We once more have a coefficient extractor enforcing the upper limit
of the sum and we find

$$2 [z^n] \frac{1}{1-z} (1+z)^{n+2}
\sum_{k\ge 0} {k+2\choose 2} (-1)^k z^k
= 2 [z^n] \frac{1}{1-z} (1+z)^{n+2} \frac{1}{(1+z)^3}
\\ = 2 [z^n] \frac{1}{1-z} (1+z)^{n-1}
= 2 \sum_{r=0}^{n-1} {n-1\choose r} = 2 \times 2^{n-1} = 2^n.$$

Here we see that keeping the original order of the two summations was
the better method moreover no new features appeared on changing the
order.

Comment: Sir how u arrived at second thing from first pls explain in detail as such most terms r dependemt on k and how u made it to be of something coefficient of z^r  : $$\sum_{r=0}^n \sum_{k=0}^r
(-1)^k (k+1) (k+2) {n+2\choose r-k}$$ = 
$$2 \sum_{r=0}^n [z^r] (1+z)^{n+2}
\sum_{k=0}^r {k+2\choose 2} (-1)^k z^k.$$

Comment: ${n+2\choose r-k} = [z^{r-k}] (1+z)^{n+2} = [z^r] z^k (1+z)^{n+2}.$

Comment: Well explained Sir got your pt ,btw Sir what u think of this thing the solution writer wrote do u think its correct as he got n-3Cr instead of yours n-1Cr ?https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2225725/922054

Comment: That was evaluated for $n$ instead of $n+2.$

Comment: Got the pt , ty Sir , also do u think Sir that changing the order of summation will lead to anything good ?

Comment: Consult my comment above.

Comment: This is very nicely explained Sir thx a lot i got your pt :)

Comment: Sir one last thing how u got that inside summatiom to be equal to 1/(1+z)^3 , as such shouldnt it depend on r as such ? As summation is from k=0 to r isnt ? I didnt get the meaning of "coefficient extrafactor enforces the inner range " maybe that is related to this

Comment: $[z^r] f(z) z^k = 0$ when $k\gt r$ and $f(0)$ is a constant.

Comment: Wonderful Sir , is this method very famous and is there a name to it and r there any more such problems here in stack exchange u remember ?  Where coefficient we take out and also in the inside function .

Comment: This is the [Egorychev method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egorychev_method) in formal power series. It may be extended to complex variables but that was not necessary here.

Comment: I see thank you Sir

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

I think that this is a red herring.

Consider instead
$$S_n=\sum_{r= 0}^{n-2}\sum_{k=0}^{r}(-1)^k\,(k+1)\,(k+2)\binom{n}{r-k}$$ and compute the very first values of $S_n$. You should find avery clear pattern.

Comment: But this pattern thing , its not a accurate method isnt ? As such if we do this in this case then for all binomial problems we can do stuff and check out a pattern ig isnt Sir?

Comment: @Orion_Pax. I totally agree with you that this does not prove anything.  This was just to give you an idea of what you are looking for. Cheers :-)

Comment: Finding a pattern is a first step, Orion. But it tells you what you're looking for. Then, you can try to prove the pattern holds, say, by induction.